# Proof for, Vectors sampled from $D_{(L,r)}$ have Euclidean norm at most $r\sqrt{n}$ with a high probability

Tags: lattice-crypto, lwe

For any $n$-dimensional lattice $L$ and $r > 0$, a point sampled from $D_{L,r}$  has Euclidean norm at most $r\sqrt{n}$ except with probability at most $2^{-2n}$ (where $r$ refers to the standard deviation of the distribution). I came across this statement in the paper [On Ideal Lattices and Learning with Errors Over Rings, 2012](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/230.pdf) by Peikert, Regev, Lyubashevsky. Can someone give a proof for why it is so?

Comment: https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/230.pdf   This the link. Its on page 11, Lemma 2.4

Comment: [New bounds in some transference theorems in the geometry of numbers](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01445125) has the proof.

Comment: I have checked the above mentioned paper... but couldn't quite understand it. Would be helpful if some one gave the intuition behind it.

Comment: define $D_{L,r}$ in your question to make it self contained.